# Python script to monitor values from another running script

Tags: python

I am starting a basic python job. My main script runs code that controls something. I then want a second python script to monitor these values and print them in the console. The main script is in a constant while loop so I have to have this code separate but I can't get it working.

Example Scenario:

Main script has a value of 'x' that is moving a wheel. I only access the value 'x' when it's equal to 20 so outputting values whenever x is accessed wouldn't work.
The monitor programs needs to be able to capture and output the change in between.

file1.py

```
x = 0

while True:
    x = x + 1
    if x == 20:
        print('X = 20 ... Resetting X = 0')
        x = 0
```

file2.py --

```
import file1
import time

while True:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Note -- The code above is not my exact scenario and I can't use it here because it wouldn't work since it's using a module to access an external device. But this is roughly what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Is that better. Sorry this is my first time posting

Comment: Much better.  Using a short version (MCVE) is good; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the value of the common variable to a storage point external to both the scripts. You may either write it to a file or read it from there, but I would suggest you use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). You may do something like this:

file1.py :

```
import cPickle as pickle
x = 0
while True:
    x = x + 1
    with open("shared_file.pkl","r+") as fp:
        pickle.dump(x,fp)
    if x == 20:
        print('X = 20 ... Resetting X = 0')
        x = 0
```

file2.py :

```
import cPickle as pickle
import time
x = 0
while True:
    with open("shared_file.pkl","r") as fp:
        x = pickle.load(fp)
    print x
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

I have assumed that both your scripts run from the same directory. In case they run from different ones, just give entire path from root instead of the just the `pkl` filename.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this later and tell you if it worked. :D